# How to count dots, semicolons and numbers in strings within a pandas column

Tags: python, pandas

The dataset I am working with contains a column with websites.
I would like to calculate the number of dots, semicolons, and numbers there.
I have written the following function for dots (but it guess it will be something similar for the other characteristics):

```
def c_dots(x):  
    return x['Web'].count('.')
```

to create a new column with the count of dots. I have got the error: ValueError: Series.count level is only valid with a MultiIndex

My dataset is

```
Web
0   https://www.times.com/
2   https://www.facebook.com/
4   https://www.twitter.com/
8   https://www.kaggle.com/
9   https://www.medium.com/
11  https://saarj.com/
12  https://pubs.acs.org/
13 https://www.facebook.com/107462464135489/posts...
14 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P-gJDhI4q3o
```

Help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `str.count` to pass string function to the series. However, note that `.` is a special regex character, so:

```
df['ndots'] = df['Web'].str.count('\.')
```

Output:

```
                                                  Web  ndots
0                              https://www.times.com/      2
2                           https://www.facebook.com/      2
4                            https://www.twitter.com/      2
8                             https://www.kaggle.com/      2
9                             https://www.medium.com/      2
11                                 https://saarj.com/      1
12                              https://pubs.acs.org/      2
13  https://www.facebook.com/107462464135489/posts...      5
14        https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P-gJDhI4q3o      2
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, QuangHoang. For counting the digits, I should use both isdigit and count, shouldn't I?

Comment: For counting the digit, you can use `.str.count('\d')`.